# Given an Array A of n subArrays Sn, how can I select the Array of Sn[i] members in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

Given an Array A of n subArrays Sn, how can I select the Array of Sn[i] members in Ruby?

For instance, given an Array of `languages` as the following:

```
languages = [ ['Italiano', 'it'], ["English", 'en'], ["Française", 'fr' ] ]
```

How can I obtain the Array...

```
locales_in_languages = ['it', 'en', 'fr' ]
```

...which contains all the `language[1]` objects?

Is there an easy and *'rubysh'* way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with [Array#transpose](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-transpose) method:

```
irb(main):014:0> languages = [ ['Italiano', 'it'], ["English", 'en'], ["Française", 'fr' ] ]
=> [["Italiano", "it"], ["English", "en"], ["Française", "fr"]]
irb(main):015:0> languages.transpose[1]
=> ["it", "en", "fr"]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was after. I am going to accept your answer even if steenslag posted his just a minute before you (by the way, thank you everybody!) because you used an index as I requested.

Answer (score 5):

In general it'll be:

```
array.map { |subarray| subarray[i] }
```

If you need the first (or the last) element of each array you can do:

```
array.map(&:first) # similar array.map(&:last)
```

See the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) for `Enumerable#map` method.

Btw, with Rails you can also use `&:second`, `&:third`, `&:fourth`, `&:fifth`, and even [`&:forty_two`](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/forty_two).

Comment: Thank you, and is Array#map an Array#collect alias?

Comment: Yes, map and collect is the same thing

Comment: Actually `Symbol#to_proc` was added to Ruby 1.8.7-p72, so it also works there without Rails: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc

Answer (score 3):

an alternative:

```
#encoding: utf-8
LANGUAGES = [ ['Italiano', 'it'], ["English", 'en'], ["Française", 'fr' ] ]
p LANGUAGES.transpose.last #=>["it", "en", "fr"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's called [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)

```
languages = [ ['Italiano', 'it'], ["English", 'en'], ["Française", 'fr' ]]
languages.map{|name, code| code } # => ["it", "en", "fr"]
```

By the way, calling your array `LANGUAGES` (all caps) violates ruby naming conventions (unless it's a constant. Only constants begin with capital letter).

Comment: Thank you, it's a constant (initialized in a Rails initializer for i18n).

Comment: when working with pairs it does not hurt to be more explicit: `languages.map { |name, code| code }`

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I forget about this all the time :(

Answer (score 0):

Array.collect is ok for this.

In attempt of doing things ruby-way there's no need to make things overcomplicated.-