# How can I "extract" values from a multidimensional array in a smart way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, multidimensional-array

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and Ruby 1.9.2.

Given the following multidimensional `Array`:

```
[["value1", "value1_other"], ["value2", "value2_other"], ["value3", "value3_other"]]
```

I would like to get (*note*: I would like to "extract" only the first value of all "nested" `Array`s):

```
["value1", "value2", "value3"]
```

*How can I make that in a smart way?*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Given an Array A of n subArrays Sn, how can I select the Array of Sn\[i\] members in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120244/given-an-array-a-of-n-subarrays-sn-how-can-i-select-the-array-of-sni-members)

Comment: @KL-7 - You are right, but I didn't find the question you linked before to post a new one.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [`Array#collect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-collect) to execute a block for each element of the outer array. To get the first element, pass a block that indexes the array.

```
arr.collect {|ind| ind[0]}
```

In use:

> ```
> arr = [["value1", "value1_other"], ["value2", "value2_other"], ["value3", "value3_other"]]
> => [["value1", "value1_other"], ["value2", "value2_other"], ["value3", "value3_other"]]
> arr.collect {|ind| ind[0]}
> => ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
> ```

Instead of `{|ind| ind[0]}`, you can use [`Array#first`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-first) to get the first element of each inner array:

```
arr.collect(&:first)
```

For the `&:first` syntax, read "[Ruby/Ruby on Rails ampersand colon shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ruby-on-rails-ampersand-colon-shortcut)".

Answer (score 2):

```
>> array = [["value1", "value1_other"], ["value2", "value2_other"], ["value3", "value3_other"]]
=> [["value1", "value1_other"], ["value2", "value2_other"], ["value3", "value3_other"]]
>> array.map { |v| v[0] }
=> ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
```

Comment: For clarification, there is no difference between `arr.map` and `arr.collect`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254732/difference-between-map-and-collect-in-ruby

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [["value1", "value1_other"], ["value2", "value2_other"], ["value3", "value3_other"]]

Solution1 = arr.map {|elem| elem.first}

Solution2 = arr.transpose[0]
```